# Extjs 4 - Error Message as validator?

Tags: validation, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I am locking for way to alert messages in Extjs4 to be just like validator alert ( red label with message beside the text field ).

I cannot use the validator because my error message should appear after press enter not just when type in text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[markInvalid](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-method-markInvalid)** method to apply a custom error to a field.

*But note that this mark will be cleaned when calling isValid*

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the validator like normal, just set validateOnChange: false.  The field will still validateOnBlur because that's set to true by default.  I believe enter triggers the blur of the field which will in turn validate the field with this change.

Comment: Thank you. this works fine but markInvalid is exactly what i need.